Check status of downloadHandler upon completion of content
I have a shiny app that generates and saves a report when the user clicks a button.
I want to show the save status in the button by changing its label and icon.
I am using a downloadButton to allow the user to specify the location and file name.  The report is an officer word document saved using print(obj, target).
The expected flow is:

user clicks button
button changes to "Saving..."
file dialogue opens
user selects file name/location
r attempts to save the document
if the save is successful (i.e., no errors)the button changes to "Saved"
otherwise, button changes to "Save Failed"

The actual flow is:

user clicks button
button changes to "Saving..."
button changes to "Saved"
file dialogue opens
user selects file name/location
...

The script does not wait for the user to select the file or see if the file saves correctly before changing the status to "Saved." In this case, the file is saving correctly, but the script has no way of knowing that before it prints to target, and it cannot print to target until the user provides the file name/location.
How may I revise this so that the status change is related to whether or not the file was saved without error?
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(officer)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),  # Initialize shinyjs
  uiOutput("save_bullet_reportui")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues(
    bullet_report_status = "save"
  )
  
  observeEvent(values$bullet_report_status, {
    status <- isolate(values$bullet_report_status)
    print(paste0("status changed to: ", status))
    output$save_bullet_reportui <- renderUI({
      if(status == "save"){
        downloadButton("save_bullet_report", "Save to .docx", icon = icon("file-word"))
      }else if(status == "saving"){
        downloadButton("save_bullet_report", "Saving...", 
                       icon = icon("spinner", class = "fa-spin"))
      }else if(status == "success"){
        downloadButton("save_bullet_report", "Saved", 
                       icon = icon("check", style = "color: #00AA00"))
      }else if(status == "failed"){
        downloadButton("save_bullet_report", "Save Failed", 
                       icon = icon("exclamation-triangle", style = "color: #AA0000"))
      }
    })    
  })
  
  output$save_bullet_report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      paste0("test_report_", Sys.Date(), ".docx")
    },
    content = function(file){
      
     values$bullet_report_status <- "saving"
        br_doc_obj <- read_docx() |> 
        body_add_par("hello world")

      tryCatch({
        print(br_doc_obj, target = file)
        values$bullet_report_status <- "success"
      }, error = function(e){
           shinyjs::delay(100, {
             values$bullet_report_status <- "failed"
             })
     })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

EDIT: The code is working exactly as it's told to. The print is executing without error (hence the immediate status change to "saved") but is unrelated to the download functionality. print is saving the file to the server, then once content function is complete, the downloadHandler starts the download process (i.e., launches the file dialog).  I viewed "saved" as "successfully downloaded", which isn't the same thing. That is still a relevant test, but my question is really, "How do I test that the downloadHandler completed the download process correctly so I can define the status?"
Current understanding of flow is:

user clicks the button
button changes to "saving"
file is saved to server with print
button changes to "saved"
content finishes -- the rest happens "behind the scenes"
downloadHandler launches file dialog to get the download location and file name from user
file is downloaded
[need help here to see if download had any errors]
[update status based on result]

EDIT 2: - response to @Michael Dewar
The use of browserURL() allows for the desired sequencing but does not allow the user to specify the file name or local save location. The users may generate several reports with different characteristics, so they will likely want to change the name to something meaningful.
I tried your hidden downloadButton suggestion (code below); it allows me to test different parts of the sequence and update the button accordingly, which is good. I still can't tell if the user clicks "cancel"; while I am sure the user will know if they clicked "cancel," it would be helpful to differentiate the status. I may need to just notify the user that the download was prepared, then revert the button to its initial state without indicating "success" explicitly.
One odd issue I found with the hidden downloadButton approach was the inconsistent display of the file dialog. The proposed script does some preparation work then "clicks" the downloadButton using either runjs(...) or shinyjs::click(...).
When using the shiny viewer, clicking the actionButton opens the file dialog as expected. When using a browser like Chrome, the file downloads without showing the dialog.
I thought this might be because the downloadButton was hidden, but even with it visible, clicking the actionButton fails to open the dialog. Physically clicking the downloadButton does open the dialog. So, simulating a click is not the same as actually clicking the button.  I will need more work to determine what the difference is and determine a workaround.
Here is the code in its current state:
library(shiny)
library(officer)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  conditionalPanel(
    "false", downloadButton("download_bullet_report")
  ),
  actionButton("save_bullet_report", "Run Report",
               icon = icon("file-word"),
               class = "btn-sm")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  tmp_doc_obj <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$save_bullet_report, {
    tmp_doc_obj(NULL) # clear this so we never print an older report
    updateActionButton(session, "save_bullet_report",
                       label = "Processing...",
                       icon = icon("spinner", class = "fa-spin"))
    tryCatch({
      doc <- read_docx() |>
        body_add_par("Hello World 2")
      tmp_doc_obj(doc)
      if(inherits(tmp_doc_obj(), "rdocx")){
        shinyjs::click("download_bullet_report")
        #runjs("$('#download_bullet_report')[0].click();")
      } else {
        stop("Report did not generate")
      }
    }, error = function(e){
      notif <- showNotification(e$message, duration = 5)
      updateActionButton(session, "save_bullet_report",
                         label = "Failed to make report",
                         icon = icon("exclamation-triangle", style = "color: #AA0000"))
    })
  })
  
  output$download_bullet_report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      paste0("bullet_report_", Sys.Date(), ".docx")
    },
    content = function(file){
      tryCatch({
        print(tmp_doc_obj(), target = file)
        updateActionButton(session, "save_bullet_report",
                           label = "Saved",
                           icon = icon("check"))
      }, error = function(e){
        notif <- showNotification(e$message, duration = 5)
        updateActionButton(session, "save_bullet_report",
                           label = "Failed to make report",
                           icon = icon("exclamation-triangle", style = "color: #AA0000"))
        }
      )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

To Do

change button status [solved]
show file dialogue consistently
react to user cancelling the file dialogue/download <- titular challenge


You might be running up to some limitations imposed by how the browser handles downloads.  Some browsers seem to just accept the filename as is and put it into a default folder.  You could always have a textInput that allows the user to change the file name before creation.  Or you could make a modal popup and prompt for it.  I do not see how you could force a dialog for the download location if the browser is not configured to ask.  If you're really running the app locally, you could also try some system() black magic.

I had thought that updateActionButton would work for downloadButtons but that does not appear to be the case.  Because of that I made the following code to mimic the downloadButton, but to use an actionButton.
The key idea is to handle updates inside one block of code, rather than jump back and forth with dueling observers.
library(shiny)
library(officer)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("save_bullet_report", "Save to .docx", icon = icon("file-word"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$save_bullet_report, {

        # The following appears ineffective...
        updateActionButton(session, "save_bullet_report",
                           label = "Saving...",
                           icon = icon("spinner", class = "fa-spin"))

        # ... but this works:
        notif <- showNotification("Trying to save...", duration = NULL, type = "message")
        Sys.sleep(1) # for demo only

        br_doc_obj <- read_docx() |>
            body_add_par("hello world")

        tryCatch({
            path <- file.path(tempdir(), paste0("test_report_", Sys.Date(), ".docx"))
            # stop() # uncomment to test error

            print(br_doc_obj, target = path)
            browseURL(path)

            removeNotification(notif)
            updateActionButton(session, "save_bullet_report",
                               label = "Saved",
                               icon = icon("check", style = "color: #00AA00"))

        }, error = function(e){
            removeNotification(notif)
            updateActionButton(session, "save_bullet_report",
                               label = "Save Failed",
                               icon = icon("exclamation-triangle", style = "color: #AA0000"))
        })

    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Unfortunately, updates to the buttons only seem to take effect after the R block finishes.  Thus, I do not know how to update the actionButton to show work is in progress.  However, showNotification totally works during  the report-generation block of R code.
In fact, if you want to use downloadButtons, you can use showNotification to handle multiple updates during the code.
One drawback of downloadButton is that if the report generation fails, shiny will still make the user download an empty file.  But with a self-made actionButton observer, you can only call browseURL when you're sure the report generated correctly.
This works locally.  I haven't tried the browseURL on a remote Shiny Server deployment.  But I have used browseURL to initiate downloads from a remote RStudio Server.
If browseURL doesn't work, you could always use a hidden downloadButton that gets triggered by the actionButton that you can update.

I updated my original post with some results based on your suggestion.  Your answer helped solve a couple of sidebar issues. I'm still struggling with the file dialogue response.  To your statement, "I haven't tried the browserURL on a remote Shiny Server..." this App will run locally, so it's fine if the answer assumes local.
